# How to delete numbers in file, by c++ fstream's

Tags: c++

I want to sort numbers, which is located in file (`file_1`). I decided to copy them in second file (`file_2`) and by loop: find min, then write it in 3rd file (`file_3`) and delete it in `file_2`, then do it again and agian while second file do not makes empty. How could i delete number in `file_2`? Do anyone knows?

For example.
`file_1: 14, 9, 12, 10`.
I want copy this in `file_2` -> 
`file_2: 14, 9, 12, 10`.

Then find the min and write it in `file_3` ->
`file_3: 9`.
And remove it from `file_2` -> (actually, how could i do it removing? This is my question.)
`file_2: 14, 12, 10`.

and so on...

`file_3: 9, 10`.
`file_2: 14, 12`.

`file_3: 9, 10, 12`.
`file_2: 14`.

`file_3: 9, 10, 12, 14`.
`file_2:`.

sorted `file_1 = file_3: 9, 10, 12, 14`.

Comment: There's no way to remove an number from a file except by writing out the whole file again, but without the number you want to delete.

Comment: Here's a simple way to figure out how to do this kind of a thing. Just take out a blank sheet of paper. Write down using brief, simple sentences in plain English, a step-by-step process of doing this. When done, [call your rubber duck for an appointment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging). We don't write entire programs for other people, on Stackoverflow. We always refer such questions to your rubber duck. After your rubber duck approves your proposed plan of action, simply take what you've written down and translate it directly into C++. Mission accomplished!

Answer (score 1):

You can find everything you need in here:
[ofstream](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/fstream/ofstream/)

Unless otherwise specified, opening the file with ofstream clears it. So just reopen the file 2 when you need to clear the file 2.

Answer (score 0):

As noted in the comment, you can't insert or delete characters in a file. You can read the file out, edit the read string, and overwrite the file with the string.

For what you're trying to do I would recommend you to read out the entire file and store the numbers in a container like `std::vector`. You can use `std::string.find()` to seperate the string into substrings by splitting at the `", "`. You can then use this vector to sort the numbers and write them in the new file.